# uncaught exception: AADSTS65001: even though I've re-authorized the app as an admin

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I'm building an angular7 app that's integrated within O365 as an enterprise app. It's the 5'th app I'm building this way and the integration has stayed the same.

Now out of nowhere (without even working on the AD integration type of things, have been building some forms for the last three days, no API calls to O365) it has started giving me this error in the console and just freezing the whole app as it attempts to  it.

I can still login and use the app otherwsie without a problem. I have also done another authorization prompt and re-authorized the app.

````
Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Trace ID: 40b7bcdf-0263-4fe6-84b5-602e8c132b00

Correlation ID: 632bbc20-2bea-4653-9455-5dfa59acf09d

Timestamp: 2019-01-09 18:51:12Z```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login as a tenant admin to https://portal.azure.com
2. Go to Azure Active Directory in the new portal, find your app registration there and click Grant Permissions under the Required permissions blade.
3. Go to Settings
4. Go to Required Permissions
5. Press the "Grant Permissions" button

[image]

You can only do this if you are a tenant admin.

Comment: I've done this as well at the time but didn't work. The issue has mysteriously disappeared after half an hour just as it appeared. Haven't had it since and have no idea what caused it;